# Why would unreadable data recovered from a drive be non-recoverable?

Tags: binary-analysis, encodings, binary-format, binary-diagnosis

I ran Disk Drill on a drive that was a member in a failed software RAID mirror on macOS. The drive seemed to be fine, but was showing up as "uninitialised", so the drive didn't fail as such it was a software problem with the RAID configuration.

Disk Drill (macOS app) recovery "worked", I could see the total size was about right, I could read a bunch of the images that were in the root directory.

Unfortunately I didn't try to read the Photos library. I later discovered that all the files in "Deep Scan HFS+" are corrupted: they have the correct names and the correct size, but if I open a JPG file in, say, vim I can see it's not a regular JPG format.

So I emailed Disk Drill support, because I thought there might still be some way to recover the data. They said that it's not possible, unless I had the original disk image from which I ran the recovery, which I do not.

However it seems to me that if the file names are correct, and the sizes are correct, that unless they have gone through some sort of "lossy compression" then they should actually be recoverable. Disk Drill support insist that's not the case.

So my question is: if you understand how disk recovery works, can you explain why the files can't be recovered OR some way I could potentially attempt to figure out how to "decode" the file format to make them readable again?